# Get url variable

Tags: objective-c, ipad

I have a application on iPad 1 and a PDF with several links.

The client will click on that link and I need to get its variables values and use it on my application.

Is it possible?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Does that application use a WebView to show the PDF?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a UIWebView and load the PDF in it. Something like this (note - it's untested but should get you on the right track!):

```
NSString* basePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath];
NSURL* baseurl = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:basePath];
[self.webView loadData:MIMEType:@"application/pdf" textEncodingName:nil baseURL:baseurl];
```

Comment: but it will load the information on the browser right? I need it to be used on my application

Comment: The webview is a browser, that can be used inside an application. But it only shows the main browser area, not back and forward and reload controls and such. Just try it :-)